# Как сделать автоматическое увеличение с 0 до 10? Java

Tags: java

Как сделать автоматическое увеличение с 0 до 10, чтоб уменьшить этот код, как его можно упростить, желательно наглядный пример?
Мой код:

```
    int n = 15;

    System.out.println();
    double z10 = 0, x10 = 1, v10 = 2, m10 = 3, l10 = 4, h10 = 5, g10 = 6, f10 = 7, s10 = 8, r10 = 9, t10 = 10;
    System.out.print(z10 + " " + x10 + " " + v10 + " " + m10 + " " + l10 + " " + h10 + " " + g10+" " + f10+" " + s10+" " + r10+ " " +t10);
    double ruslanacci10 = 0, k10 = 0;
    while (k10 < n) {
        ruslanacci10 = z10 + x10 + v10 + m10 + l10 + h10 + g10 + f10 + s10 + r10 + t10;
        z10 = x10;
        x10 = v10;
        v10 = m10;
        m10 = l10;
        l10 = h10;
        h10 = g10;
        g10 = f10;
        f10 = s10;
        s10 = r10;
        r10 = t10;
        t10 = ruslanacci10;
        System.out.print(" " + ruslanacci10);
        k10++;
    }

    System.out.println();
    double z9 = 0, x9 = 1, v9 = 2, m9 = 3, l9 = 4, h9 = 5, g9 = 6, f9 = 7, s9 = 8, r9 = 9;
    System.out.print(z9 + " " + x9 + " " + v9 + " " + m9 + " " + l9 + " " + h9 + " " + g9+" " + f9+" " + s9+" " + r9);
    double ruslanacci9 = 0, k9 = 0;
    while (k9 < n) {
        ruslanacci9 = z9 + x9 + v9 + m9 + l9 + h9 + g9 + f9 + s9 + r9;
        z9 = x9;
        x9 = v9;
        v9 = m9;
        m9 = l9;
        l9 = h9;
        h9 = g9;
        g9 = f9;
        f9 = s9;
        s9 = r9;
        r9 = ruslanacci9;
        System.out.print(" " + ruslanacci9);
        k9++;
    }

    System.out.println();
    double z8 = 0, x8 = 1, v8 = 2, m8 = 3, l8 = 4, h8 = 5, g8 = 6, f8 = 7, s8 = 8;
    System.out.print(z8 + " " + x8 + " " + v8 + " " + m8 + " " + l8 + " " + h8 + " " + g8+" " + f8+" " + s8);
    double ruslanacci8 = 0, k8 = 0;
    while (k8 < n) {
        ruslanacci8 = z8 + x8 + v8 + m8 + l8 + h8 + g8 + f8 + s8;
        z8 = x8;
        x8 = v8;
        v8 = m8;
        m8 = l8;
        l8 = h8;
        h8 = g8;
        g8 = f8;
        f8 = s8;
        s8 = ruslanacci8;
        System.out.print(" " + ruslanacci8);
        k8++;
    }

    System.out.println();
    double z7 = 0, x7 = 1, v7 = 2, m7 = 3, l7 = 4, h7 = 5, g7 = 6, f7 = 7;
    System.out.print(z7 + " " + x7 + " " + v7 + " " + m7 + " " + l7 + " " + h7 + " " + g7+" " + f7);
    double ruslanacci7 = 0, k7 = 0;
    while (k7 < n) {
        ruslanacci7 = z7 + x7 + v7 + m7 + l7 + h7 + g7 + f7;
        z7 = x7;
        x7 = v7;
        v7 = m7;
        m7 = l7;
        l7 = h7;
        h7 = g7;
        g7 = f7;
        f7 = ruslanacci7;
        System.out.print(" " + ruslanacci7);
        k7++;
    }

    System.out.println();
    double z6 = 0, x6 = 1, v6 = 2, m6 = 3, l6 = 4, h6 = 5, g6 = 6;
    System.out.print(z6 + " " + x6 + " " + v6 + " " + m6 + " " + l6 + " " + h6 + " " + g6);
    double ruslanacci6 = 0, k6 = 0;
    while (k6 < n) {
        ruslanacci6 = z6 + x6 + v6 + m6 + l6 + h6 + g6;
        z6 = x6;
        x6 = v6;
        v6 = m6;
        m6 = l6;
        l6 = h6;
        h6 = g6;
        g6 = ruslanacci6;
        System.out.print(" " + ruslanacci6);
        k6++;
    }

    System.out.println();
    double z5 = 0, x5 = 1, v5 = 2, m5 = 3, l5 = 4, h5 = 5;
    System.out.print(z5 + " " + x5 + " " + v5 + " " + m5 + " " + l5 + " " + h5);
    double ruslanacci5 = 0, k5 = 0;
    while (k5 < n) {
        ruslanacci5 = z5 + x5 + v5 + m5 + l5 + h5;
        z5 = x5;
        x5 = v5;
        v5 = m5;
        m5 = l5;
        l5 = h5;
        h5 = ruslanacci5;
        System.out.print(" " + ruslanacci5);
        k5++;
    }

    System.out.println();
    double z4 = 0, x4 = 1, v4 = 2, m4 = 3, l4 = 4;
    System.out.print(z4 + " " + x4 + " " + v4 + " " + m4 + " " + l4);
    double ruslanacci4 = 0, k4 = 0;
    while (k4 < n) {
        ruslanacci4 = z4 + x4 + v4 + m4 + l4;
        z4 = x4;
        x4 = v4;
        v4 = m4;
        m4 = l4;
        l4 = ruslanacci4;
        System.out.print(" " + ruslanacci4);
        k4++;
    }

    System.out.println();
    double z3 = 0, x3 = 1, v3 = 2, m3 = 3;
    System.out.print(z3 + " " + x3 + " " + v3 + " " + m3);
    double ruslanacci3 = 0, k3 = 0;
    while (k3 < n) {
        ruslanacci3 = z3 + x3 + v3 + m3;
        z3 = x3;
        x3 = v3;
        v3 = m3;
        m3 = ruslanacci3;
        System.out.print(" " + ruslanacci3);
        k3++;
    }

    System.out.println();
    double z2 = 0, x2 = 1, v2 = 2;
    System.out.print(z2 + " " + x2 + " " + v2);
    double ruslanacci2 = 0, k2 = 0;
    while (k2 < n) {
        ruslanacci2 = z2 + x2 + v2;
        z2 = x2;
        x2 = v2;
        v2 = ruslanacci2;
        System.out.print(" " + ruslanacci2);
        k2++;
    }

    System.out.println();
    double z1 = 0, x1 = 1;
    System.out.print(z1 + " " + x1);
    double ruslanacci1 = 0, k1 = 0;
    while (k1 < n) {
        ruslanacci1 = z1 + x1;
        z1 = x1;
        x1 = ruslanacci1;
        System.out.print(" " + ruslanacci1);
        k1++;
    }

    System.out.println();
    double z0 = 0;
    System.out.print(z0);
    double ruslanacci0 = 0, k0 = 0;
    while (k0 < n) {
        ruslanacci0 = z0;
        z0 = ruslanacci0;
        System.out.print(" " + ruslanacci0);
        k0++;
    }
```

**Вывод**

```
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 55.0 110.0 219.0 436.0 869.0 1734.0 3463.0 6920.0 13833.0 27658.0 55307.0 110604.0 221153.0 442196.0 884173.0

0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 45.0 90.0 179.0 356.0 709.0 1414.0 2823.0 5640.0 11273.0 22538.0 45067.0 90089.0 180088.0 359997.0 719638.0

0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 36.0 72.0 143.0 284.0 565.0 1126.0 2247.0 4488.0 8969.0 17930.0 35824.0 71576.0 143009.0 285734.0 570903.0

0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 28.0 56.0 111.0 220.0 437.0 870.0 1735.0 3464.0 6921.0 13814.0 27572.0 55033.0 109846.0 219255.0 437640.0

0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 21.0 42.0 83.0 164.0 325.0 646.0 1287.0 2568.0 5115.0 10188.0 20293.0 40422.0 80519.0 160392.0 319497.0

0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 15.0 30.0 59.0 116.0 229.0 454.0 903.0 1791.0 3552.0 7045.0 13974.0 27719.0 54984.0 109065.0 216339.0

0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 10.0 20.0 39.0 76.0 149.0 294.0 578.0 1136.0 2233.0 4390.0 8631.0 16968.0 33358.0 65580.0 128927.0

0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 6.0 12.0 23.0 44.0 85.0 164.0 316.0 609.0 1174.0 2263.0 4362.0 8408.0 16207.0 31240.0 60217.0

0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 6.0 11.0 20.0 37.0 68.0 125.0 230.0 423.0 778.0 1431.0 2632.0 4841.0 8904.0 16377.0

0.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 5.0 8.0 13.0 21.0 34.0 55.0 89.0 144.0 233.0 377.0 610.0 987.0

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Поставил `double`, потому что числа большие.

Comment: Можно начинать изучать структуры данных и объекты.

Comment: Увеличение чего? Не очень понятен вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В принципе весь ваш код можно свести к чему-то такому:

```
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;

public class TestNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println();
        Integer startLength = 11;
        double[] startData = new double[startLength];
        for(int index = 0;index<startLength;index++){
            startData[index] = (double) index;
        }


        for(int numberOfData = startLength;numberOfData>0;numberOfData--) {
            int n = 15;
            double[] data = new double[numberOfData];
            for (int index = 0; index < numberOfData; index++) {
                data[index] = startData[index];
                System.out.print(data[index] + " ");
            }
            double ruslanacci10;
            for (int k10 = 0; k10 < n; k10++) {
                ruslanacci10 = DoubleStream.of(data).sum();
                System.arraycopy(data, 1, data, 0, data.length - 1);
                data[data.length - 1] = ruslanacci10;
                System.out.print(ruslanacci10 + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Результат работы:

```
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 55.0 110.0 219.0 436.0 869.0 1734.0 3463.0 6920.0 13833.0 27658.0 55307.0 110604.0 221153.0 442196.0 884173.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 45.0 90.0 179.0 356.0 709.0 1414.0 2823.0 5640.0 11273.0 22538.0 45067.0 90089.0 180088.0 359997.0 719638.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 36.0 72.0 143.0 284.0 565.0 1126.0 2247.0 4488.0 8969.0 17930.0 35824.0 71576.0 143009.0 285734.0 570903.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 28.0 56.0 111.0 220.0 437.0 870.0 1735.0 3464.0 6921.0 13814.0 27572.0 55033.0 109846.0 219255.0 437640.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 21.0 42.0 83.0 164.0 325.0 646.0 1287.0 2568.0 5115.0 10188.0 20293.0 40422.0 80519.0 160392.0 319497.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 15.0 30.0 59.0 116.0 229.0 454.0 903.0 1791.0 3552.0 7045.0 13974.0 27719.0 54984.0 109065.0 216339.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 10.0 20.0 39.0 76.0 149.0 294.0 578.0 1136.0 2233.0 4390.0 8631.0 16968.0 33358.0 65580.0 128927.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 6.0 12.0 23.0 44.0 85.0 164.0 316.0 609.0 1174.0 2263.0 4362.0 8408.0 16207.0 31240.0 60217.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 6.0 11.0 20.0 37.0 68.0 125.0 230.0 423.0 778.0 1431.0 2632.0 4841.0 8904.0 16377.0 
0.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 5.0 8.0 13.0 21.0 34.0 55.0 89.0 144.0 233.0 377.0 610.0 987.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Если целью является именно использование циклов и уменьшить размер кода. Но скорость из-за этого не сильно возрастет.

Comment: А можно ли как-нибудь увеличивать double[] startData = new double[] {0d, 1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d, 6d, 7d, 8d, 9d, 10d}; до неопределённого количества? как k10++ только для 0d, 1d, 2d ячеек

Comment: @RuslanGadzhiev Приведите пример, пожалуйста. В смысле сделать массив `new double[] {1, 2, 3, 4.... xxx}`? Если да, то конечно можно: надо просто будет сделать цикл от 0 до n и заполнить этот массив числами. Я хотел так сделать тоже, но не стал добавлять слишком много циклов. )

Comment: как это сделать на данном примере?

Comment: можно ли сделать так, чтобы компилятор выдавал результат в таком порядке как если перевернуть пирамиду

Comment: Поправил код, теперь там есть можно задавать размер стартового массива.
Насчет поворотов и т.д. - создайте новый вопрос. А то тут можно далеко и глубоко уходить. Скорее всего можно, но надо понимать, что значит - повернуть.

Comment: у нас вывод начинается с 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 и далее по убыванию верно? нужно чтобы он начинал с нуля, но форма вывода осталось как есть сейчас. получается он должен смещать строчку с нулями и писать следующую строчку перед ней

Comment: создан новый вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/886660/как-сделать-чтобы-код-выводил-в-консоль-в-обратную-сторону