# как сделать чтобы код выводил в консоль в обратную сторону?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;

public class TestNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println();
        Integer startLength = 11;
        double[] startData = new double[startLength];
        for(int index = 0;index<startLength;index++){
            startData[index] = (double) index;
        }


        for(int numberOfData = startLength;numberOfData>0;numberOfData--) {
            int n = 15;
            double[] data = new double[numberOfData];
            for (int index = 0; index < numberOfData; index++) {
                data[index] = startData[index];
                System.out.print(data[index] + " ");
            }
            double ruslanacci10;
            for (int k10 = 0; k10 < n; k10++) {
                ruslanacci10 = DoubleStream.of(data).sum();
                System.arraycopy(data, 1, data, 0, data.length - 1);
                data[data.length - 1] = ruslanacci10;
                System.out.print(ruslanacci10 + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

результат работы:
вывод должен быть таким как есть сейчас

```
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 55.0 110.0 219.0 436.0 869.0 1734.0 3463.0 6920.0 13833.0 27658.0 55307.0 110604.0 221153.0 442196.0 884173.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 45.0 90.0 179.0 356.0 709.0 1414.0 2823.0 5640.0 11273.0 22538.0 45067.0 90089.0 180088.0 359997.0 719638.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 36.0 72.0 143.0 284.0 565.0 1126.0 2247.0 4488.0 8969.0 17930.0 35824.0 71576.0 143009.0 285734.0 570903.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 28.0 56.0 111.0 220.0 437.0 870.0 1735.0 3464.0 6921.0 13814.0 27572.0 55033.0 109846.0 219255.0 437640.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 21.0 42.0 83.0 164.0 325.0 646.0 1287.0 2568.0 5115.0 10188.0 20293.0 40422.0 80519.0 160392.0 319497.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 15.0 30.0 59.0 116.0 229.0 454.0 903.0 1791.0 3552.0 7045.0 13974.0 27719.0 54984.0 109065.0 216339.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 10.0 20.0 39.0 76.0 149.0 294.0 578.0 1136.0 2233.0 4390.0 8631.0 16968.0 33358.0 65580.0 128927.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 6.0 12.0 23.0 44.0 85.0 164.0 316.0 609.0 1174.0 2263.0 4362.0 8408.0 16207.0 31240.0 60217.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 6.0 11.0 20.0 37.0 68.0 125.0 230.0 423.0 778.0 1431.0 2632.0 4841.0 8904.0 16377.0 
0.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 5.0 8.0 13.0 21.0 34.0 55.0 89.0 144.0 233.0 377.0 610.0 987.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

программа работает в убывающем виде, вывод начинается от последнего к первому.
выглядит как пирамида вниз головой от кончика до основания.

для возрастающего вида, вывод начинается от нулевого до последнего

```
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 5.0 8.0 13.0 21.0 34.0 55.0 89.0 144.0 233.0 377.0 610.0 987.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 6.0 11.0 20.0 37.0 68.0 125.0 230.0 423.0 778.0 1431.0 2632.0 4841.0 8904.0 16377.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 6.0 12.0 23.0 44.0 85.0 164.0 316.0 609.0 1174.0 2263.0 4362.0 8408.0 16207.0 31240.0 60217.0 
0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 10.0 20.0 39.0 76.0 149.0 294.0 578.0 1136.0 2233.0 4390.0 8631.0 16968.0 33358.0 65580.0 128927.0
....итд
```

выглядит как пирамида, строится с кончика до основания

как привести этот возрастающий вывод к выводу похожему на убывающий, по форме пирамиды вниз головой. 
получается он должен смещать строчку с нулями и писать следующую строчку перед ней итд от кончика до основания вверх.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ясно. )
Суть в том, что тебе надо поменять первый цикл.
Должно быть как-то так:

```
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;

public class TestNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println();
            Integer startLength = 11;
            double[] startData = new double[startLength];
            for(int index = 0;index<startLength;index++){
                startData[index] = (double) index;
            }


            for(int numberOfData = 1;numberOfData<startLength+1;numberOfData++) { // <-- Изменения тут
            int n = 15;
            double[] data = new double[numberOfData];
            for (int index = 0; index < numberOfData; index++) {
                data[index] = startData[index];
                System.out.print(data[index] + " ");
            }
            double ruslanacci10;
            for (int k10 = 0; k10 < n; k10++) {
                ruslanacci10 = DoubleStream.of(data).sum();
                System.arraycopy(data, 1, data, 0, data.length - 1);
                data[data.length - 1] = ruslanacci10;
                System.out.print(ruslanacci10 + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: не совсем, так он просто строит пирамиду от нулевого к последнему, то-есть порядок вывода правильный, но после System.out.println(); он переходит на следующую строку оставляя первую строку на предыдущей, а нужно чтобы он выведенную строку перевёл на новую строку, а следующий вывод писал на первой строке. То-есть порядок вывода соответствует, но вывод должен быть похож как показано в исходном варианте.

Comment: Тогда для этого надо тогда уже использовать модули, которые форматируют данные на экране. А в чем сокральный смысл такого особенного поведения? Если это будет писаться в файл - результат будет всё равно правильный, на экране тоже. А где он может не правильный?

Comment: Другими словами в пункте "результат работы:" показано 2 вывода: второй вывод который показывает как работает программа, но сам вывод должен иметь форму первого вывода

Comment: А в чем сокральный смысл такого особенного поведения? направление вывода в не стандартной форме, если представить простые цифры, то у нас есть -2 -1 0 1 2, у нас есть 2 направления в которую идут цифры. "-" показывает это направление в левую сторону. между цифрами получается баланс. если наш вывод сравнить с выводом простых цифр, то наш вывод соответствует только 0 1 2. правой стороне, для баланса нужна левая сторона, -2 -1 0. обратный вывод